# Color Swatch Catalogue - Pulling from Hex# Color codes from database table - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, variables, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create a color swatch catalogue page that based on table column HEX (list of hex color codes). There are a few hundred and creating them in a stylesheet would take forever. Because of that, I wanted to create a Wordpress page template with variable code generating the background color.

I was able to successfully pull the data as text but I am having a hard time figuring out how to use the HEX column as background color style variable.

My first step was to be able to make sure I was able to pull in the data from that column, next step is to create the color swatches (colored boxes based on the hex code in the column) and hoping to figure out how to create a filter next.

Here is the code I have placed in the Wordpress page template. How would I create a variable for a style or class that pulls from my Wordpress database table that I created:

```
<?php

    global $wpdb;
    $result =  $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_colors' );
    foreach ($result as $print ) { ?>

    <div><p><?php echo $print->HEX; ?> - <?php echo $print->Description; ?></p></div>

    <?php }
    ?>
```

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find the answer. Perhaps I am not looking at the correct method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use the hex and do inline css? ```<div style="background-color: <?= $print->HEX; ?>;"></div>```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much, I think it wasn't working because I was putting in <?php echo....

Comment: haha glad it worked, in case you didn't know ```<?= 'hello world' ?>``` is short hand for ```<?php echo 'hello world' ?>```

Comment: That's good to know too. Total noob here, I am doing a course and I haven't gotten to that point yet. Best way of learning is doing! Thanks!